# Change color if visited links on Azure DevOps

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

We have a TFS server running, now re-branded as Azure DevOps Server.

On some dashboards we use a Markdown widget to provide some information, including links. These links turn up blue before visiting them, but after visiting a link the link turns very dark, maybe even black. This makes it hard to distinguish visited links from regular text.

I remember in the dark ages before CSS this was a browser setting. Nowadays I assume that is handled by CSS, and that stylesheet is probably provided by the TFS installation.

Is there any way to change that color/style, so visited links still stand out?

Comment: Do you can share a screenshot hot it look like?

Comment: Hi Johan, are you using dark theme or light theme in your theme setting? Besides, as Shayki Abramczyk mentioned, better to include a screenshot and reproduce step, so we could have a better understanding  here.

Comment: Johan, any update on this ticket? If not solved, would you mind to expand your description with screenshots.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I've noticed this behaviour as well. We've created a WIKI page that we use as the home page. On this page we've added some links to other Azure Devops pages (to work items, queries, feeds). Visited links are black, others are blue. Since neither of them is underlined, it's very hard to notice that these are links.

Comment: @Stanislas Sorry this sounds a behavior caused by Wiki code. May not related to Azure DevOps itself. Have you tried use the solution Johan mentioned below.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I don't understand what you mean by "caused by Wiki code". Though I did notice the following. Our start page is displayed via a README.md file. If I look at the README.md file through the repository everything looks fine. If I look at it through the start page then the links are black.
Also, I do understand that Johans answer below would probably work, but it seems absurd to need a workaround for this.

Comment: I agree that adding this code for every link is very old school markup. I’d say pre-css, but since markdown has no css-equivalent maybe we’re using the wrong language if we expect more than just basic behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, we can just mix HTML with Markdown? This seems to work:

```
 <font color="blue">blue text</font>
```